# reinstalling El Capitan

Tags: reinstall, osx-el-capitan, imac

I wiped all info off my computer and now want to reinstall the operating system. It was on OS X El Capitan. Originally it was one of the 'leopards'. Yes, it's old but it works fine for kids and school work.
My problem is the system tells me 'This item is temporarily unavailable'. Try again later, as I try to install. 
I need to get this up and running again. Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thank you. Suzanne

Comment: You may find an answer more quickly by searching over at http://askdifferent.com  but the first thing they, or we, ask, is "Which Apple model are you using?"